# fopen is freezing the program

Tags: c, terminal, fopen

I'm making a small C program to count the number of lines of a file but every time I compile and run it in my terminal, the program is freezing (not showing any error, but the program can't read the next inscrutions)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void    find_word (void);    

int     main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

        find_word();

        return 0;    
}     

void    find_word (void)
{

        FILE *file;
        int character;
        int line_number;

        file = NULL; 
        character = 0;
        line_number = 0;
    
        file = fopen ("word_source.txt", "r");

        if (file == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error\n");
            exit (0);
        }

        printf("%c", character);
        character = fgetc(file);
        while (character != EOF)
        {
            if (character == '\n')
            {
                line_number++;
            }
        }

        fclose(file);

        printf("%d", line_number);

}
```

I have no idea what's the problem, so I created another file and this one works:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int     main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *file = fopen ("word_source.txt", "r");
        
            if (file == NULL)
                printf("No");
        
            else
                printf("Yes");

            return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 character is already fgetc(file)

Comment: @zelph14 your code reads exactly one character from the file. You want to read all characters of the file.

Comment: "Error" is not a useful error message, you're writing it to the wrong stream, and it seems odd to `exit(0)` and claim success on that failure.  Try: `const char *path = "word_source.txt"; if( (file = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL) { perror(path); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`

Comment: @user3121023 oh yes it was that simple... thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` isn't freeezing here. *Your* codeappears to be freezing because you have an infinite loop here:

```
character = fgetc(file);   // read one char from file

while (character != EOF)   // this loop is repeated indefinitely
{                          // because character never changes inside the loop
  if (character == '\n')  
  {
    line_number++;
  }
}
```

You want this:

```
while (1)
{
  character = fgetc(file);   // reads a character from the filee

  if (character == EOF)      // if end of file
    break;                   // stop the loop

  if (character == '\n')     // is character read a newline?
  {
    line_number++;           // increment line number
  }
}
```

or more compact:

```
while ((character = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
{
  if (character == '\n')     // is character read a newline?
    line_number++;           // increment line number
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler added a shorter version. I suppose this is more idiomatic, but maybe harder to understand for a beginner.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The first version was clear and easily understood.  The "idiomatic" C with the assignment crammed into the `while` statement is a construct so bug-prone that industry coding standards such as MISRA regarding code reliability and human safety ban it from compliant code.  MISRA C:2004, 13.1, MISRA C++:2008, 6-2-1, MISRA C:2012, 13.4, and CERT, EXP45-C all apply, and probably quite a few others. See https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP45-C.+Do+not+perform+assignments+in+selection+statements for just one example.

Comment: Protip: if your program 'stops', check CPU use.  If 0, it's blocked, if 100%, it's looping.